# How to set initial value to atom when parent component re-render?

Tags: reactjs, jotai

## Environment

- react: 18.2
- jotai: 2.2 (latest)

## Problem

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

    return <ChildComponent val={val} />;
}


const myAtom = atom(0);
const ChildComponent = ({ val }) => {
    // I want to sync [val -> myAtom]
};

const Child_ChildComponent = () => {
    const valFromAtom = useAtomValue(myAtom);
    ...
};
```

Should I make new atom every re-render to sync with props ?

`useHydrateAtoms` did not working.